# Вставить полученный ответ js

Tags: php, javascript

Есть таблица с динамическим выпаданием полей

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var product = ["<?php echo  $product; ?>"];
var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td width='10%'><input type='text'  id='tags' name='product_name[]' autocomplete='on' required class='form' onchange='product_name()'></td>" +
            "<td width='10%'><input name='model_product[]'  id='model'  type='text'   ></td>" +
            "<td width='20%'><input style='width:45%' type='text' name='price[]'> <input style='width:45%' readonly type='text' name='currency[]' ></td>"+
            "<td width='15%'><input type='text' name='total[]' style='width:90%'  id='i1'  ><input type='hidden' name='product_id[]'  class='form-control'  ></td>" +
            "<td width='10%'><img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/minus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1); sum_total(this);'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id=i2  value='0' size='1' >" +
            "<img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/plus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).prev().val(~~jQuery(this).prev().val()+1);sum_total(this);'></td>" +
            "<td width='10%'><input type='text'   name='oll_total[]' value='0' class=i3></td>" +
            "<td width='10%'><a id='delete_row' class=' minus' onclick='sum_delete(this)'><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='<?php echo $text_delete_product; ?>'></a></td></td>");
        $('input#tags').autocomplete({ source: product});
        $('input#tags').autocomplete({
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var product_name = ui.item.value;
                console.log(product_name); здесь при клике я получаю выбранное значение  
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/autocomplete',
                    data:{"product_name":product_name},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#model').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
$("#delete_row").click(function(){
    if(i > 1 ){
        $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
     }
   });
 });
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
});
```

`console.log(product_name); здесь при клике я получаю выбранное значение` и хочу передать на сервер и вставить ответ `"<td width='10%'><input name='model_product[]'  class='model'  type='text'   ></td>" +` подскажите как это можно сделать?

Comment: Можете подробно сказать где хотите поставить ответ? и вы вообще получаете правильный ответ вашего ajax запроса?

Comment: да ответ приходит правильный  а вставить нужно здесь   `"<td width='10%'><input name='model_product[]'  id='model'  type='text'   ></td>" +`

Comment: То есть этот фрагмент кода у вас уже есть да? и в нем где нужно вставить? вот эту часть подчеркните пожалуйста?

Comment: да,  ответ  `success: function(data){ $('.model').html(data);}` и можно его вставить  `<td width='10%'><input name='model_product[]'  class='model'  type='text'   ></td>`  `class='model' `

Comment: если ответ принять не форме то все норм ` <div class="model"></div>`

Comment: у вас путаница какая то, отдельными строками напишите ответ и то место где нужно впихнуть этот ответ, Это строка `$('.model').html(data)`  означает что в выбранном элементе очищается html и в место него вставляеться новый, Но у вас это просто тег input.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59485/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-sender1050).